# How to display only the first value in Views, by overriding TPL.PHP?

Tags: views

I am trying to override the output of one field in Views, and I need it to print only the first value of the field.

Like:

Unfortunately my knowledge of PHP and Drupal-API are very low, so I hope to get some help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the View edit page using the UI without editing the template.

- Go to `admin/structure/views`
- Edit the view in question
- Under Fields, select the field in question
- Expand the section **'Multiple field settings'**
- Set as: 'Display **1** value(s) starting from **0** (first item is 0)
- Save your view and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with template level, you can use pager option. User pager and select " Display a specified number of items" to 1.

If you want a specific condition to be passed to display only one item, then please do mention what your views shows, and the template variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [hook_views_pre_render(&$view)](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

which will provide you the option to change any value of any views.
to change the specific view

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {

if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
// then check for $view->result[0] and you will get the first row where you can edit your stuff
}

}
```